# Cloc check files that include text

Tags: cloc

[Cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) has a way to exclude files that contain text using `--exclude-content=<regex>`. I’m looking for a way to do the opposite. How can I check files that only include certain phrases? I've tried `cloc . --exclude-content='/^((?!import).)*$/s'` but it doesn't give the desired results. I have also tried writing an ignored file using `--ignored` but that only gives the ignored reason, and not the line count.

How would I be able go about only including files that contain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was [added to cloc.](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc/issues/720)

```
cloc-master/./cloc ../Folder --include-content="import Nimble" --by-file-by-lang --quiet > QuickAndNimbleFiles.txt
```